# line start string and end string matches then it needs to replace end string of a line and ignore any string that matches in between of same line

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting, regular-expression

Require a shell script for the below issue

```
elecj_test: |1009676|F|269.13348200|3|348415|237.06|0.00|0.00|||SSPPPSSSPSSS|UNTESTED||
```

If a line starts with **elecj_test:** and ends with **||** it needs to replace with **| |**

Here Space is added in between **| |**

In the middle of the line if it is found **||** it must not replace only it must replace at end of the line.

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward to do in [tag:awk] -- What attempts have you made to solve it?

Comment: I tried with sed and grep, grep it can find using grep ^elecj ||$ but it cannot replace

Comment: What should the script do with lines that don't begin with `elecj_test:` and end with `||`?  Filter them out?  Output the lines unchanged?

Comment: the script can ignore the rest of the lines if it does not match the above condition

Comment: Does "ignore" mean "print as-is" or "not print"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my sed command that edits the ending `||` as requested:

```
sed -n 's/^\(elecj_test:.*|\)|$/\1 |/p'
```

Matches starting "elecj_test:" and ending "||", captures the line up to (but not including) the final "|" with parentheses, and replaces with the captured string, followed by a space and a "|", and prints the edited line.

It's not parameterized to adapt to different starting/ending strings, so perhaps not a high quality answer, but maybe you need a quick one-time command.

Comment: "did not work" -- any errors, no output, wrong output?

Comment: sed -n 's/^\(elecj_test:.*|\)|$/\1 |/p'    Thanks ,this is working fine

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), using the pipe as the field separator:

- test that the first field equals "elecj_test: " and the last field is empty and the 2nd last field is empty.
- If true, set the 2nd last field to be a space.

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
  $1 == "elecj_test: " && $NF == "" && $(NF - 1) == "" {
    $(NF - 1) = " "
    print
  }
' file
```

```
elecj_test: |1009676|F|269.13348200|3|348415|237.06|0.00|0.00|||SSPPPSSSPSSS|UNTESTED| |
```